# bash if and then statements both run

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement

I'm running this in bash and even though there is a .txt file it prints out "no new folders to create" in the terminal.
Am I missing something?

```
FILES=cluster-02/*/*

for f in $FILES
do        
        if [[ $f == *."txt" ]] 
        then
                cat $f | xargs mkdir -p
        else
                echo "No new folders to create"
        fi
done;
```

Comment: You're looping over multiple files, so the first file may trigger the `if` and the second file can show the `else`.

Comment: thanks! so how would i go about editing this so that if there are no text files present it runs the else statement?

Comment: Have a look at https://shellcheck.net for solving some of the issues you have

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the first comment, the behaviour is indeed as you might expect from your script: you run through all files, text files and other ones. In case your file is a text file, you perform the `if`-case and in case your file is another type of file, you perform the `else`-case.

In order to solve this, you might decide not to take the other files into account (only handle text files), I think you might do this as follows:

```
FILES=cluster-02/*/*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over multiple files, so the first result may trigger the `if` and the second can show the `else`.

You could save the wildcard result in an array, check if there's something in it, and loop if so:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob

FILES=( foo/* )

if (( ${#FILES[@]} )); then
    for f in "${FILES[@]}"; do
        if [[ $f == *."txt" ]]; then
            echo $f
        fi
    done
else
    echo "No new folders to create"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create an array containing a list of files
# This is safer to avoid issues with files having special characters such
# as spaces, glob-characters, or other characters that might be cumbersome
# Note: if no files are found, the array contains a single element with the
#       string "cluster-02/*/*"
file_list=( cluster-02/*/* )

# loop over the content of the file list
# ensure to quote the list to avoid the same pitfalls as above
for _file in "${file_list[@]}"
do
   [ "${_file%.txt}" == "${_file}" ] && continue # skip, not a txt
   [ -f "${_file}" ]                 || continue # check if the file exists
   [ -r "${_file}" ]                 || continue # check if the file is readable
   [ -s "${_file}" ]                 || continue # check if the file is empty
   < "${_file}" xargs mkdir -p --    # add -- to avoid issues with entries starting with -
   _c=1
done;
[ "${_c}" ] || echo "No new folders to create"
```